# How to check network interface type is Ethernet or Wireless on Windows using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, network-programming, wlanapi

I need to find out the network interface type is Wired or Wireless on PC.

I have tried using `QNetworkInterface` class which provides `Adapter Name`. But adapter name can be changed by user on Windows. On Mac, I can check for interface type as `eth0` or `eth1` since it is same for all users.

I also tried `QNetworkConfiguration::bearerType`, But I am getting configuration as Ethernet i.e. BearerEthernet for both wired and wireless configuration.

Is there any other way to find out network interface type in Qt or using Windows platform specific APIs?

Answer (score 0):

This Native Wifi API example can help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706749%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you. _WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO structure in the above link provides only interface description and state which are not useful to check interface type is wireless or ethernet.