How to get active internet connection in Windows winapi32
I am trying to get information about an active internet connection.
I can see if I have WiFi connected:
bool networkConnectionInfo::isWifiConnected(connectionDetails& details)
{
    HANDLE hClient = NULL;
    DWORD dwMaxClient = 2; // Version of client
    DWORD dwCurVersion = 0;
    DWORD dwResult = 0;
    PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST pIfList = NULL;
    PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO pIfInfo = NULL;
    PWLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES pConnectInfo = NULL;
    DWORD connectInfoSize = 0;
    WLAN_OPCODE_VALUE_TYPE opCode = wlan_opcode_value_type_invalid;

    dwResult = WlanOpenHandle(dwMaxClient, NULL, &dwCurVersion, &hClient);
    if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return false;
    }

    dwResult = WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, NULL, &pIfList);
    if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        WlanCloseHandle(hClient, NULL);
        return false;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pIfList->dwNumberOfItems; i++)
    {
        pIfInfo = (WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO*)&pIfList->InterfaceInfo[i];
        if (pIfInfo->isState == wlan_interface_state_connected)
        {
            dwResult = WlanQueryInterface(hClient,
                &pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid,
                wlan_intf_opcode_current_connection,
                NULL,
                &connectInfoSize,
                (PVOID*)&pConnectInfo,
                &opCode);

            if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                details.ssid = std::string((char*)pConnectInfo->wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid.ucSSID,
                    pConnectInfo->wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid.uSSIDLength);

                details.signalQuality = static_cast<int>(pConnectInfo->wlanAssociationAttributes.wlanSignalQuality);

                WlanFreeMemory(pConnectInfo);
                WlanFreeMemory(pIfList);
                WlanCloseHandle(hClient, NULL);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    WlanFreeMemory(pIfList);
    WlanCloseHandle(hClient, NULL);
    return false;
}

but I do not know how to check the ethernet connection. Also if Ethernet & WiFi are both connected and Windows is using a wired connection to communicate with the internet - how can get this information?
Also, I have not found a way to check if there is a cellular connection active.

Not sure what the question is, but you can use the INetworkListManager interface. Its GetNetworks method returns an iterator over INetwork instances you can query.

@IInspectable I am using it but it does not help too much. Do you have more detailed suggestions?

You could try to use InternetGetConnectedState function to retrieve the connected state of the local system.Returns TRUE if there is an active modem or a LAN Internet connection, or FALSE if there is no Internet connection, or if all possible Internet connections are not currently active.

@Jeaninez-MSFT I know all that trivial stuff. INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN can be ethernet or Wifi but how to know if it is Ethernet or Wifi? It is my question, not if I have an active internet connection

If you want to distinguish whether the connection is Ethernet or Wifi. I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016166/check-if-windows-computer-on-ethernet-via-c
